# Is it possible to change the token split rules for a Spacy tokenizer?

Tags: python, regex, token, tokenize, spacy

The (German) spacy tokenizer does not split on slashes, underscores, or asterisks by default, which is just what I need (so "der/die" results in a single token).

However it does split on parentheses so "dies(und)das" gets split into 5 tokens. Is there a (simple) way to tell the default tokeniser to also not split on parentheses which are enclosed by letters on both sides without a space?

How exactly are those splits on parentheses defined for a tokenizer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The split on parentheses is defined in this line, where it splits on a parenthesis between two letters:

https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/23ec07debdd568f09c7c83b10564850f9fa67ad4/spacy/lang/de/punctuation.py#L18

There's no simple way to remove infix patterns, but you can define a custom tokenizer that does what you want. One way is to copy the infix definition from `spacy/lang/de/punctuation.py` and modify it:

```
import re
import spacy
from spacy.tokenizer import Tokenizer
from spacy.lang.char_classes import ALPHA, ALPHA_LOWER, ALPHA_UPPER, CONCAT_QUOTES, LIST_ELLIPSES, LIST_ICONS
from spacy.lang.de.punctuation import _quotes
from spacy.util import compile_prefix_regex, compile_infix_regex, compile_suffix_regex

def custom_tokenizer(nlp):
    infixes = (
        LIST_ELLIPSES
        + LIST_ICONS
        + [
            r"(?<=[{al}])\.(?=[{au}])".format(al=ALPHA_LOWER, au=ALPHA_UPPER),
            r"(?<=[{a}])[,!?](?=[{a}])".format(a=ALPHA),
            r'(?<=[{a}])[:<>=](?=[{a}])'.format(a=ALPHA),
            r"(?<=[{a}]),(?=[{a}])".format(a=ALPHA),
            r"(?<=[{a}])([{q}\]\[])(?=[{a}])".format(a=ALPHA, q=_quotes),
            r"(?<=[{a}])--(?=[{a}])".format(a=ALPHA),
            r"(?<=[0-9])-(?=[0-9])",
        ]
    )

    infix_re = compile_infix_regex(infixes)

    return Tokenizer(nlp.vocab, prefix_search=nlp.tokenizer.prefix_search,
                                suffix_search=nlp.tokenizer.suffix_search,
                                infix_finditer=infix_re.finditer,
                                token_match=nlp.tokenizer.token_match,
                                rules=nlp.Defaults.tokenizer_exceptions)


nlp = spacy.load('de')
nlp.tokenizer = custom_tokenizer(nlp)
```